# How to output above the last printed line?

Tags: python, command-line, printing, format, output

Is there a way in python to print something in the command line above the last line printed? Or, similarly to what I want to achieve, remain the last line intact, that is, not overwrite it.

The goal of this is to let the last line in the command line a status/precentage bar.

Output example:

```
File 1 processed
(0.1% Completed)
```

Next refresh:

```
File 1 processed
File 2 processed
(0.2% Completed)
```

Next refresh:

```
File 1 processed
File 2 processed
File 3 processed
(0.3% Completed)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
erase = '\x1b[1A\x1b[2K'

def download(number):
    print(erase + "File {} processed".format(number))

def completed(percent):
    print("({:1.1}% Completed)".format(percent))

for i in range(1,4):
    download(i)
    completed(i/10)
    sleep(1)
```

Works in my python 3.4, final output is:

```
File 1 processed
File 2 processed
File 3 processed
(0.3% Completed)
```

If you want read more about terminal escape codes see:
Wikipedia's [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) article.

As requested, example with a space:

```
from time import sleep
erase = '\x1b[1A\x1b[2K'

def download(number):
    print(erase*2 + "File {} processed".format(number))

def completed(percent):
    print("\n({:1.1}% Completed)".format(percent))

print("\n(0.0% Completed)")
for i in range(1,5):
    download(i)
    completed(i/10)
    sleep(1)
```

The final output is:

```
File 1 processed
File 2 processed
File 3 processed
File 4 processed

(0.4% Completed)
```

Comment: And what if I wanted to leave a blank line in between the block of files processed and the percentage? I think that would be quite tricky

Comment: If I understand correctly, not at all, I have added example to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `\r` command. This could do the trick.

```
for i in range(2):
    print '\rFile %s processed' % i
    print '(0.%s%% Completed)' % i,
```

Output is:

```
File 0 processed
File 1 processed
(0.1% Completed)
```

Comment: This works but just for this specific case. Image I've got several outputs from different processes (multiprocessing module) and I want to keep a track of percentage advanced.

Comment: @PyCV If you have multiple processes and you want to coordinate display, they should all send their output to one place to do it. If you were doing a multiprocessing pool, `imap_unordered` would be a good way.